How does array padding works in Stack?
The following question refers to x86 assembly, and little endianness.
Suppose I have the following code in C:
unsigned char myID[10] = "211866744";

How will this array be saved in memory?
My professor mentioned that since it is 10 bytes, it will be padded with zeros to the nearest multiple of 4, resulting in a total size of 12 bytes before being written to memory.
My question is, how will this padding be applied? Will the memory layout be (left is lower address in memory):

Lower address <-- myID[0..3], myID[4..7], myID[8..11] --> Higher address

or:

Lower address <-- myID[0..1], myID[2..5], myID[6..9] --> Higher address

Regarding these layouts, where will the padding zeros be added? Will they be placed to the left (lower address) of the first element, to the right of each group, or to the right of the last element?
I believe the layout myID[0..3], myID[4..7], myID[8..11] makes more sense as memory is typically read sequentially from lower to higher addresses.
Additionally, concerning the null terminator, how can we distinguish it from the padding zeros used to achieve the 12-byte alignment, given they share the same encoding?
Please relate to my example in your answer so I can understand.

Your professor is wrong. This is an array of bytes and there is no padding. Your first example is correct. There is also no alignment requirement, which maybe your professor is thinking about. A byte array does not need to start on a 32-bit word boundary, for example.

"x86 assembly": You are showing C, not assembly. Your professor is wrong. First of all, the stack layout is not determined by the C language. It is up to the compiler, with a few details determined by the CPU architecture and ABI in use. Whether there will be padding depends e.g. on the alignment requirements of other variables on the stack that the compiler chose to layout next to your array. If the compiler is able to put another variable directly before/after the array, why wouldn't it do so? Even if there is padding, why would the compiler spent the effort to zero it?

That being said, it may be that the compiler choses to add such a zeroed padding because that happens to make it possible to use the array more efficiently on the particular CPU architecture (e.g. because it allows loading the tail of the array into a 32bit register directly). But that would be purely an optimization made by the compiler for the specific circumstances.

What your professor perhaps meant is that gaps may be left after a variable to keep things aligned. Internal to a struct this would be called padding. In your example, there is no padding and the "holes" are just that and not part of the variable. Your first example should be modified to myID[0..3], myID[4..7], myID[8..9] There are no elements 10 or 11.

@user17732522 yes he's referring to that optimization, so in this case how the memory will look like

@David I do not know whether that actually makes sense on x86. And even if, it would only make sense if the compiler has context where the array is being used. In any case, it doesn't affect how the array can be used by you.

@AviBerger thanks for the explanation so in case of padding what the last 4 bytes (In higher address) will look like given that last char is "4" which is 0x34? will it be 0x00000034 or 0x00003400

Look at this example of what one compiler does with 3 char arrays. It reserves 16 bytes on the stack to keep the stack aligned, though the arrays don't need that much space, the arrays are contiguous in memory, and some of the 16 bytes are unused. The unused bytes don't have any value loaded into them, their contents is whatever was in them before.

The unused bytes' contents in this case is whatever was in them before. Could be anything. Some other compiler might zero them. Some other hardware and compiler might not keep things aligned this way. Platform and implementation specific. I wouldn't call this padding, I wouldn't count on the alignment bytes being there or having any specific value.

@user17732522: If the array was larger (16 bytes or more) or variable-length, the x86-64 System V ABI would specify that it's aligned by 16.  (Which is an odd intrusion into the private internals of a function that isn't normally visible across function boundaries for non-static arrays, so no real reason for the ABI to specify that, but it's in the ABI doc anyway for some reason.  It is in practice what GCC does.)

You can look at what compilers actually do: https://godbolt.org/z/vn1YhnKxs - after aligning the stack by 16 (with sub rsp, 24 on function entry), clang puts the array at RSP+8 (so aligned by 8 but not by 16), in a function that has another 4-byte array.  GCC puts the longer one at RSP+6, the shorter at RSP+2, so neither aligned.  Weird choice.

alignof(myID) == 1 so the compiler is free to put it anywhere at any alignment (if it doesn't optimize it away).

It is common for an Application Binary Interface (ABI), a document that specifies rules for programs and parts of programs interacting on a particular platform, to specify that the stack pointer must be maintained as a multiple of 4, 8, or 16 bytes. In this case, when a program is increasing the amount of stack space it needs, it must increase it by a multiple of the required alignment1.  If the compiler needs 10 more bytes for some purpose, and the required alignment is 4 bytes, the compiler must adjust the stack pointer to provide at least 12 more bytes of memory. 10 of those bytes will be then used for the new purpose.
However, this is not commonly regarded as padding. The additional two bytes are not part of the array and are not strongly associated with it. The program may use them for other purposes.
Also, it is common that a compiler will generate a routine that allocates all of the stack space it will need at the start of the routine and releases it at the end. In this case, the compiler will plan all of the space it needs for objects it will store on the stack plus various administrative needs, such as a return address, a frame pointer, and so on. So an array of 10 bytes will not be allocated separately with two additional bytes. All of the space needed will be calculated, possibly including padding needed for alignments of some objects, and then the total will be rounded up to the ABI alignment requirement.
None of this is specified by the C standard; it is a feature of each individual computing platform.

Regarding these layouts, where will the padding zeros be added?

The compiler will place the array wherever it was written to place the array. There is no particular need to put it at the lower address or the higher address. A common model when planning layout of multiple objects is to put the objects with the strictest alignment requirements at the lowest address and follow them with objects with decreasingly strict requirements (or vice-versa), as this minimizes wasted space.
The excess bytes will not necessarily contain zeros. There is generally no need to set them to anything, so they will be left with whatever values they hold from prior operations.

Additionally, concerning the null terminator, how can we distinguish it from the padding zeros used to achieve the 12-byte alignment, given they share the same encoding?

The null terminator of a string is the first null byte in the string. (Since it marks the end of a string, it is also the only null byte in the string.)
The compiler will know where the end of the array is because it laid out the array in the first place.

Footnote 1: That's simplifying some details.  The compiler might need some of that space for its own use, like saving the caller's frame pointer and/or the return address.  x86's call instruction already pushes the return address onto the stack, so on function entry the stack is already offset from the alignment it had before the call.  (e.g. x86-64 System V and Windows x64 require RSP % 16 == 0 before a call, and on function entry guarantee that RSP % 16 == 8 so an odd number of 8-byte pushes and/or e.g. sub rsp, 24 will re-align the stack.) On most RISCs, non-leaf functions need to save the return address from a register to the stack themselves, in space they reserve.
Fun fact: AArch64 can enforce stack alignment in hardware so any access using SP when SP is misaligned will fault, unlike on x86-64 where you usually only notice the ABI violation when calling a function where the compiler optimized something using SSE instructions to copy 16 bytes at a time (e.g. a struct or some array elements).
